# pip not recognizing "-r" command

Tags: python, pip

I am new to using flask, and I am trying to set it up on my computer through terminal. I download pip/python3, create a virtual environment and then activate it. Then I try running "pip install –r requirements.txt".

When I do this, I get a huge error written in red, most of which is a traceback. But the first line says: "Invalid requirement: '–r'"

I don't understand how -r is an invalid argument? What am I doing wrong? This is the command everyone says to use, so I assume I made a mistake earlier.

Comment: Could you post your full error?

Comment: looks like you're using the wrong symbol ? `pip install -r requirements.txt`  (not `pip install –r requirements.txt`)

Comment: @PRMoureu is on to something, though it's not obvious (at least with the font I see). If you copy/pasted the command from e.g. a blog which automatically converts the regular ASCII minus to a typographically more satisfying alternative glyph, it won't work (and there should be a law against blogs like that).

Comment: Are you copy pasting the pip install command. Looks like the hyphen in `-r` is getting converted to something else

Comment: `–r`, not `-r`? They look very similar, but those are two different characters.

Answer (score 13):

Some time this could happen if you are copy pasting command, as mentioned in comments.
Please delete '-' before '-r' and retype hyphen.

Wrong command

```
pip install –r requirements.txt  # wrong command , observe hyphen length
```

Correct command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt  # correct observe hyphen length , little smaller
```