# Pycharm terminal does not recognize -r command

Tags: python, pycharm, requirements.txt

I'm trying to run the command :

```
pip install -r common\requirements.txt
```

In the pycharm terminal. However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement :'-r'
```

When I execute the command above without "-r", pycharm tells me to add it to the command.

Can you please help me identify the issue?

Comment: Is it on Windows?

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060652/348851

Comment: Yes' its on windows

Answer (score 0):

As user defiant wrote, the solution was to replace the "-" character with a manually written one, because when you do copy+paste on this command, it registers the "-" as a different character